# How Do I Unlock Tools (unclickable) in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm looking to use certain basic tools in Illustrator like the Star Tool, and the majority of tools are shaded out and un-clickable. I am only able to select a handful of tools to draw for example, as seen below.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "tools are shaded out and unclickable"? Tools don't get "locked" (And unlock all has nothing to do with selecting any tool). I'm afraid screenshots may be necessary... or just relaunch the app maybe.

Comment: My *only* possible **guess** is that you're either trying to work on a locked layer, or you in some sort of "mode" like Isolation Mode... but even then tools aren't "unclickable". They simply present a little "don't" symbol when you try and use them. And many of the menu items, especially the Object menu, aren't available unless an object is *selected*.

Comment: @Scott thanks for answering, I've posted an answer below that contains a screenshot of the kind of un-clickable status of both objects and several tools in the tool bar

Comment: @HughMerkle - please don't post extra details in the answers section. You should instead [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/158630/edit), and add extra details there.

Comment: Are you modifying the toolbar? Because the tool listing from where it should be used does not have a divider between options as far as im aware. If so thise just indicate that the tool is in fact allready in the toolbar just under another tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu you are showing is the one that pops up when you press on the three dots on the bottom of the toolbar. This is for customizing the toolbar, it is **not** generally for selecting tools. Tool dimmed out in this menu just means the tool is allready in the toolbar, not that you can't select the tool. Although, granted if this tool isn't in the toolbar you can still use to select the tool this way. A bit bad gui to be honest.

Instead the shape tools are now in the toolbar under the other shape tools there is a small notch next to a tool button that has many options, just press and hold for more tools.

[image]

**Image 1**: the fact that a tool is grayed out in the all tools menu does not mean its disabled. It just means its allready in the toolbar.

Comment: Oh, well spotted, but what version of Illustrator is that? I'm still on CC 2018 - and it doesn't have those three dots, or that useless menu ;)

Comment: @BillyKerr CC version do practice a thing thing called "progressive disclosure" which i think is a design anti-pattern but still so there needs to be a mechanism to hide and show gui items. I mean its in my oppinion impossible to even learn core concepts with the afault gui that adobve goves users on clean isntall in cc. It should be in cc2018 too but its hidden in the view menu.

Comment: .... Nice catch!

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks for the help.